# Is it possible to see football on VLC without web browser?

Tags: vlc

In Linux, is it possible to see football in VLC player without www browser from address https://areena.yle.fi/tv/ohjelmat/30-901?play=1-50003218

Comment: No, that is a HTML page.... if you can determien the URL for the actual stream, it would be possible, depending on the protocol used

Comment: If you look at the source of the page I believe it's this URL -   `<meta property="og:url" content="https://areena.yle.fi/tv/ohjelmat/30-901?play=1-50003218">`. You should be able to pass that directly to `vlc`.
.

Answer (score 0):

In VLC you can specify the stream's URL directly and bypass having to run it in a web browser. If you launch VLC you can click the 'open media' button and then click the 'Network' tab.

#### Example

[image]

From the command line you can simply invoke it like so with the same URL:

```
$ vlc http://....
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`yle-dl`](https://github.com/aajanki/yle-dl) tool. You should be able to use it to pipe the content to vlc (or other media player) with `--pipe` option. For example:

```
yle-dl --pipe URL | vlc -
```